# Convert Object to generic type. Object must implement IConvertible

Tags: c#, entity-framework, type-conversion

I wanted to convert the object to generic type the following way:

```
public void convert<T>(T entityType, Object instance) where T : Type
    {
        var temp = (T)Convert.ChangeType(instance, typeof(T));
    }
```

"entityType" represents type of my Entity generated from DB. But it throws error:

> Object must implement Iconvertible.

Is there a way to cast the object to a custom class?

Comment: The error is just telling you how it can be done: inheriting from IConvertible

Comment: and shouldn't the constraint rather be `where T : IConvertible`? otherwise `typeof(T)` wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Ok, but "entityType" is a Type, how do I pass my custom class as type T for that to work?

Comment: Hmm, could it be, that you are not searching for conversion, but merely like to cast as f.ex.: **var temp = yourObject as YourType;** or in generic manner **var temp = (T)instance**? Btw: Your convert method does not need the parameter _T entityType_ since you only need the type which is already passed as generic parameter.

Comment: Yes, I want to cast it but if I do something like this: "var temp = (T)instance;" it throws error: 'Unable to cast object of type 'MyClass' to type 'System.Type'.'

Comment: Ok, but this means, that you your <T> is System.Type which not really make sense, since your MyClass shall be an entity which does not derive from System.Type. What is <T> in your example Code?